# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage (UIWeb) - Xcode

Tags: ios, uiwebview, app-store-connect, wkwebview, xcode11

I have seen that there are several questions referring to the same problem. Basically the same thing happens to me I have updated my libraries at project level in xcode with pod update for all my libraries I use the search engine (cmd + shift + f) to find if UIWebView is used but I can't find any results.

[image]

Also at console level I use the following command `grep -r "UIWebView" .` But I only get this in the result.

```
Binary file ./TrustDefenderMobile.framework/TrustDefenderMobile matches
Binary file ./TrustDefenderMobile.framework/Versions/A/TrustDefenderMobile matches
Binary file ./TrustDefenderMobile.framework/Versions/Current/TrustDefenderMobile matches
Binary file ./Library/TrustDefender.framework/TrustDefender matches
Binary file ./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/A/TrustDefender matches
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/A/Headers/TrustDefender.h:#define THMUseUIWebView                 THM_NAME_PASTE(THM_PREFIX_NAME, THMUseUIWebView)
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/A/Headers/TrustDefender.h:EXTERN NSString *const THMUseUIWebView;
Binary file ./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/Current/TrustDefender matches
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/TrustDefender.h:#define THMUseUIWebView                 THM_NAME_PASTE(THM_PREFIX_NAME, THMUseUIWebView)
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/TrustDefender.h:EXTERN NSString *const THMUseUIWebView;
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Headers/TrustDefender.h:#define THMUseUIWebView                 THM_NAME_PASTE(THM_PREFIX_NAME, THMUseUIWebView)
./Library/TrustDefender.framework/Headers/TrustDefender.h:EXTERN NSString *const THMUseUIWebView;
Binary file ./PardosChicken.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/macbook.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate matches
```

Well the truth is I do not understand. I am launching a new application and I have updated my project to WKWebView but the horror message from apple keeps coming. If you could give me a solution it would be excellent, I have been days with this problem without being able to send my app to the store.

Comment: It looks like you need an updated version of the TrustDefenderMobile framework or remove this framework

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, @Paulw11 observation helped me find the error, as I indicated, I was being guided by the xcode search engine that did not give me any results, however in the console it indicated a TrustDefender library, After documenting me I understood that it is a framework that serves for online payments, however, this framework is no longer used in the project and is suspended. Simply choose to remove it and resubmit the app to App Store Connect accepted smoothly. Hope this helps those having similar issues, as advice I would say the console guide and the results you get, as you will see, xcode didn't quite work for me.

Comment: How did you solve the issue with TrustDefender lib? @dbenitobaldeon